# MongoDB/RethinkDB Use ODM or not?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, rethinkdb, odm, database

I am building a boilerplate app in koajs for later use. I cannot decide if I should use an ODM or not. I can define my schemas using ES6 classes and even if I use something like mongoose I will probably end up writing a lot of custom validators so these are not really deciding factors. Odm engines contain a lot of functionality that I will hardly ever use.

- Are there any other advantages of using odm over writing custom methods?
- How much is the overhead caused by the odm engine, is it worth to not use it?
- How would you compare the two options in terms of performance, would you say badly optimized queries will perform worse?

Answer (score 0):

The questions you're asking require a lot more background into your environment, stack, and application functionality. Whenever you're parsing the results and generating convenient objects out of them, you're spending CPU time doing that, plus you'll be incurring additional memory overhead generating objects versus just dealing with the raw query results.

Based on my understanding on ODMs, the advantage of using one is the convenience when writing app logic as well as easy code readability. This factor should not be taken lightly for larger projects and can help you organize and implement new features more quickly than without it.

If you're worried about performance, you can always test? But I don't think an ODM is going to make or break your system if you use one.